# codenameone - how to set the minSdkVersion on android build

Tags: codenameone

I set the property:

```
codename1.android.targetSDKVersion=8
```

but the result of a build is resetting it as follows:

```
android:minSdkVersion="15"
  android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21"  />
```

Is this the minimum sdk version?

Answer (score 1):

When using the GUI to edit properties you need to set them using just the property e.g. `android.targetSDKVersion`. When editing `codenameone_settings.properties` directly you need to use `codenameone.arg.android.targetSDKVersion` (notice the `.arg.` section).

I wouldn't change the target SDK version or the min SDK version (which to your question can be manipulated via `android.min_sdk_version` as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html)) as both won't work properly. I'm assuming you want to target older devices which you can do by disabling the google play services using `android.includeGPlayServices=false`.

Comment: I also need to support older devices (in my case down to API 15). @Shai would you mind elaborating on why it won't work to change the `android_min_sdk_version` ? But if I follow your advice and disable Google play services, will the in app purchases still work ?

Comment: If you disable google play services in-app-purchase will no longer work as they are implemented there by Google. Setting the minimum version will have no effect when you include google play services as it will be overriden by it